# Outlook HTML other way to use Position Absolute

Tags: html, css, outlook

I know Outlook doesn't allow Position: Absolute. Is there any other alternative to this?
I need something similar to position: Absolute that works in Outlook HTML, as I don't want to be dependent on margins and paddings.

Thank you

Comment: No alternative at all of position: absolute; for desktop targeted email client like Outlook. You can just cut as a image which part is need to display as z axis layer instead position but it will be break if you need it as a responsive. You can overcome this solution using "media query" for web email client.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Hanif , unfortunately, "media queries" do not solve my problem because I needed the HTML to be responsive based on variables of a file that changes daily. This means we have to change the HTML every day in order to make it responsive.